# Three JS error relative reference - import

Tags: javascript, import, three.js

I have an error when im trying to import OrbitControls from Three JS , i installed it by NPM. The import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js'; works just fine, but i want to import in my js OrbitControls and gives me this error =

index.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

My HTML Code =

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT CODE =

```
import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement );
```

A picture of how i have my folders in my space =

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3ZWy.png)

Comment: You have to use an import-map. This question has already been asked here [Failed to resolve module specifier three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160473/failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-thre) Keep in mind that import maps don't yet work on Safari & Firefox, so you'll need to use the shim in that answer for those browsers.

Comment: @Marquizzo doesn't work for me, i dont know what to do, i tryed everything !

Comment: You tried the import map and it didn't work? If so, you should edit your initial question with that additional info.

Comment: @Marquizzo i solved it ! Thank you very much for your help, now i will investigate what is shim and how to use it :) . You are a genius ! :D