# Problems with importing THREE.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

So I tried to import the THREE.js file and the GLTFLoader but I can't make it work. I googled and couldn't find the right solution so that's why I'm asking here.

Here's the HTML:

```
<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Here's the JS:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.151.3/three.min.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.151.3/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
var scene, camera, renderer, model;

init();
function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 5;

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load('img/futuristicface.glb', function (gltf) {
    model = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(model);
  });
  animate();
}
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

The error that pops up is:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: The CDN file you import for your GLTFLoader includes such a reference (a not-relative one that the browser cannot and will not resolve), so you can't use that. Why does everyone keep doing this CDN stuff for this? Please install three as a package and include them like that, then you have full control of your app.

Comment: @somethinghere I like to use CDNs that's why. So I should install three.js with NPM and then it should work?

Comment: @dnos either that or use the correct CDN implementation as per the [documentation option 2](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation)

Comment: If you want control, definitely during development, don't use a CDN. What if you work on this when you have no internet connection? CDNs are something you should use at the end if you require that optimisation. In the meanwhile, it is indeed best to isntall and use the modules you have locally. Development will be much easier. Or do what @Ryhazerus suggests.

Comment: @Ryhazerus So I installed it with NPM and now have this code in my js: import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'; 
but its still the same error.

Comment: You'll need to use an import map so the browser can properly reference the `three` references in `GLTFLoader`. [Here is an example](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/use-importmap-for-paths-in-examples-jsm/37354/3).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to resolve module specifier three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160473/failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-three)