Trouble with loader path syntax (No CDNs) / ThreeJs npm node js / Relative references must start with either "/", "./" or
Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
I have read several questions about this in and out of SO, but it is still not very clear to me where the incommunicability is.
A couple of posts I'v read about it many users recommended to use CDNs instead, but so where is the point of having installed via npm(?), it's my first time working with modules instead, I'd like to learn this approach, but this starting point doesn't make things clear to me heheh
Anyway before the Loader URL started with 'node_modules/...' while now I added '/' despite the fact that in theory I think it is not needed right?
As you can see also WebGLs are imported in the same way but it doesn't cause the error, only the GLTFLoader import for now, I also read that it is not recommended to have module imports from different folders, so why node modules installs all packs with this folder hierarchy?
Screenshots of my directories:


Code:


/* SUPPORT WARN SUPPORT WARN SUPPORT WARN SUPPORT WARN SUPPORT WARN SUPPORT WARN SUPPORT WARN SUPPORT WARN */ 
import WebGL from '/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/capabilities/WebGL.js';

if ( WebGL.isWebGLAvailable() ) {

} else {

    const warning = WebGL.getWebGLErrorMessage();
    document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( warning );

}
/* ________________________________________________________________________________________________________ */ 


/* MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN MAIN */
import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js';


/*
import { DRACOLoader } from '/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
*/


import { GLTFLoader } from '/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

/* RENDER */
const container = document.querySelector( '#container' );
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: false, antialias: true });
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000);
renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
renderer.setSize( container.innerWidth, container.innerHeight );

container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        /* render resize on container */
        function resize() {     
            if (container == null) {
                console.warn('The container element is null.');
                return;
            }
            
            try {
                renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
                camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            } catch(e) {
                console.warn('An error occured while resizing the renderer:');
                console.error(e);
            }

        };
        window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
        


/* SCENA - CAMERA */

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 5, 11,);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);



/* GEOMETRY */
 
const groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20, 20, 32, 32 );
groundGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2 );
const groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ 
    color: 0xffffff,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
const groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh ( groundGeometry, groundMaterial );
scene.add(groundMesh);



/* SPOT LIGHT */

const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight ( 0xffffff, 3, 100, 0.5, 0.5 );
spotLight.position.set( 0, 25, 0 );
scene.add(spotLight);
spotLight.intensity = 1000;




/* ANIMATION PLANE */
function animatePlane() {
    requestAnimationFrame (animatePlane);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

animatePlane();


/* GEOMETRY */


const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath('/public/models/');
loader.load('/public/models/untitled.gltf', function (gltf) {
    const mesh = gltf.scene;
    mesh.position.set (0, 1.05, -1);
    scene.add(mesh);
});

/* ________________________________________________________________________________________________________ */ 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Unbounded:wght@200;400;900&display=swap');
@font-face{font-family:"FontAwesome";font-display:block;src:url(../webfonts/fa-v4compatibility.woff2) format("woff2"),url(../webfonts/fa-v4compatibility.ttf) format("truetype");}


/* HEADER HEADER  HEADER HEADER  HEADER HEADER  HEADER HEADER  HEADER HEADER  HEADER HEADER  HEADER HEADER  HEADER HEADER  HEADER HEADER  */

.header {
    background-color: rgb(249, 255, 255);
    -moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 80px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 80px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    box-shadow:5px 5px 80px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  }
  
.IDentity {
    font-family: 'Unbounded', cursive;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  
.header h1{
    font-family: 'Unbounded', cursive;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
.header .bio{
    font-family: 'Unbounded', cursive;
    font-size: 0.84rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*align-items: baseline;*/
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
  
#name {
    margin: 0; font-size: 2rem ; font-weight: 400;
  }

/* LANDING SECT LANDING SECT LANDING SECT LANDING SECT LANDING SECT LANDING SECT LANDING SECT LANDING SECT LANDING SECT LANDING SECT */

.sectUNO {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  background-position:center; 
  height:66vh;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 40px;}

.landZERO {
   /* background-image: url(public\img\download2023-11-03T213308403.png); */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    /*margin-top: 10vh;*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center; 
    height:66vh;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

#info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    display:block;
}

/* sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO sectUNO */

.sectUNO {
    bottom: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-size: cover;*/
    min-width: fit-content;
    height: 69vh;
}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>tryTR</title>
    <style>
        body { padding: 10; }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
        <div class="IDentity">
    
          <h1 id="name">xxx</h1>

          <div class="bio"> <p style="  font-size: 1rem ;">123456789
            <!-- Graphic Designer, Digital Artist, Creative Director -->
            </p>
            <p style="margin-right: 75px; font-weight: 500; font-size: 1rem;">Portfolio</p>
          </div> 
    
        </div>
    </div>


    
    <section class="landZERO" id="container">

        <div id="info">Description</div>
               
            <script type="module" src="/main.js">
        
            </script>
    
    </section>



    <section class="sectUNO">

    </section>

    <footer style="color: rgb(153, 118, 76); height: 30px; ">

    </footer>

</body>
</html>



I guess the error is probably due to conflicts between modules dependencies, should I mention that I also have 'vite' installed too(?), is also inside node_modules folder.
Am i stepping into the point where I need to know more about/use WebPacks?


not really, I already saw this post before posting my question, sounds logically correct to me, but i can't make the html understanding that part of code, the part in between the script tags  ''imports''... etc, is all white out on VS Code like no understood parameters / formatting

Does the web server provide node_modules?

I guess so, since i'm running it locally and having all the node dependacies on folder

Where does the error come from? I think you need an import map for three. Why do you not bundle the app? It's option 1: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Please post code, logs, error messages and other text as text, not images of text. You don't need Webpack in addition to Vite. You can bundle the app with Webpack and Vite and you should prefer Vite for new projects.

Yes i think that can be a problem but im facing an issues of importing the map in the script tag as u can see from the last pic i added to the question, i also had that thought, to use something like WebPack as  i mentioned in the end of my question, under the snippet code, i never did it but i saw that can be maybe a solution so while bundling it is going to be recompiled and should avoid path and conflicts right?

You have multiple ways to solve the problem. Bundling is an alternative to import maps. Using a bundler still requires correct import paths. Why do you not follow the Three.js documentation?

Ok, got it for image of txt, makes sense. I didn't use WebPacks yet, while Vite is embedded in this project but just approched it, can be a tool to bundle too? Sorry for the noob question I'm getting here selflearning, I'am following the documentation of Threejs, but i just change workflow from cdn to npm etc and facing this confused me and made me step in webpacks etc that i didn't know before

Where have you found Webpack or import maps in the current documentation? https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation I don't see it. Why are you not following this documentation? Your code doesn't look like the code in the documentation.

I look trought several documentation, and im happy to read a lot if need, but I faced this problem while importing a Gltf file trought a loader that is embedded in the directory of node_modules but it conflict, and this specific case I didn't find a reply on the documentation, while when I'm not using a Gltf file but just like 'BoxGeometry' that doesn't require a loader I don't get this problem, I found this that is quite close [link] (https://discourse.threejs.org/t/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-three/38262/6) look also at the oct22 topics

Your code doesn't look like the code in the link. Which several documentations use imports from node_modules?

already this not documentation but example that you provide to me too [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160473/failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-three) also here link is talking about installing node js to load and menage dependacies and it create automatically for u that directory hierarchy

The problem in your question can be solved with a import map. I tried to solve this problem. In the comments I found out that that's not the actual problem.  Here is the documentation for the GLTFLoader. Follow the official documentation until you understand what you're doing. Then, you can start to tweak the configuration. As a beginner, you shouldn't try to configure the project yourself, if there are much better alternatives.

Ok, thanks and sorry, can you be more constructive critic and try to reply to me on: why should i change the directory of something created automatically by a build tool ?
From something made to 'help you'  to ending up having maybe too many different path for similar dependancies? thanks

Who told you to change the directory? Everything is in node_modules. The bundler knows that and looks there. There is no reason to add node_modules to the path. That's called Node.js module resolution. Why do you import modules from examples? I don't see it in the documentation. Whatever you've read before, throw it away and restart step by step with the official documentation.

Nobodies, since you told me two times 'your code doesn't look like in the documentation' I'm comparing it out, sorry, so I can fix this by importing a map or bundling it, importing a map locally doesn't work as I showed you true my other mistake of the image of a text, and neither true CDN like here [link] (https://discourse.threejs.org/t/importing-from-cdn/54090/3) because it will cause this [Cannot use import statement outside a module], so should I bundle it? Sorry if I'm not seeing something, I very appreciate your time I'm trying to learn more as I can

I don't get it. You're a beginner. There is a step by step guide. And you're trying it your way. Why?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

in relative paths remember './' is essentially the path to the folder the executing file is in. '../' is the containing folder.
consider the tree below:
drive:\
...
ancestorfile
folder1
  |---file
  |---executingfile
  |---file
  |
  |---folder1_a
       |---file
       |---file
  |
  |---folder1_b
      |---folder1b_1
           |---nestedfile
           |---file
      |
      |---file

so if in 'executingfile' you wanted to point to
'ancestorfile' it would be:
'../ancestorfile'
how about 'nestedfile'?:
'./folder1_b/folder1b_1/nestedfile'
or above 'ancestorfile'?:
'../../ancestorsancestorfile'
or the same folder as 'executingfile'?:
'./file'
of course this is limited to local paths
if your WebGL.js file is located in the node_modules/three/examples/jsm/capabilities/
import WebGL from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/capabilities/WebGL.js';

Similarly, if your GLTFLoader.js file is located in the node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/ directory relative to your JavaScript file, you should use:
import { GLTFLoader } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js


yes, thanks, but does not fix the issue, the issue is right there, my GLTFLoader is in the node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/ directory and even if my path is written correctly doesn't change the Error im getting in the DevTool console
